# WPF/Clickonce vs Web app du jour

Tags: asp.net, wpf, silverlight, wcf

My company is considering starting development on a new application.  I like the idea of WPF/WCF deployed via clickonce instead of the web app (including silverlight).  Other than losing some platform independence I think WPF wins out over the web app in every way.  IMO, the web app only makes sense for creating a public facing view of your system.  Call it the internet cafe rule.  If the app doesn't need to serve the public in general and your clients are running windows then isn't WPF a no brainer?  I know the answer is always, "it depends" so can anyone offer their criteria for choosing one paradigm over the other?

BTW, I found this while researching this topic:
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2007/12/20/reasons-for-choosing-wpf-over-aspnet-for-very-large-project/

It's a bit dated but he makes some good points.

Comment: Probably this question cannot be answered without a description of what the app will do.

Comment: I agree, tofium.  Thats why I'm wondering what criteria people used to make their decision.

Answer (score 0):

If the choice is between WPF and Silverlight and it's just an internal app then you're probably better off going for WPF.  I haven't really used Silverlight, but from my limited knowledge of it, it is basically a cut-down version of WPF for the web, you should be able to build a richer application using WPF than you could with Silverlight.

Comment: The distinction I'm trying to make is not between WPF and silverlight per se, but between WPF and a web application (ie browser).

Comment: I think it all depends on what your application needs to do.  Timescales could be a factor too, you could probably write it a lot quicker using a language / technology you're more familiar with rather than tackling something with a potentially steep learning curve.  Obviously if you're proficient in a few languages this will be less of an issue.  Quicker doesn't necessarily mean better, but I know what business users can be like for pushing deadlines!